# parsing a Complex JSON Structure

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse this JSON in Java.

```
{
  "json": {
    "abc": 0,
    "def": "100",
    "ghi": 1,
    "jkl": "0000000000",
    "mno": "3",
    "pqr": "COLS, COMPLETE",
    "stu": 2,
    "vwx": "0000010000",
    "yz": "00",
    "a123": 31,
    "b123": 1,
    "c123": "1270",
    "d123": "2",
    "e123": "00",
    "f123": 1,
    "g123": "0000001000"
  },
  "_indexes": {
    "c123": [
      "1270"
    ],
    "h123": [
      "1270"
    ]
  },
  "_d": false,
  "_dd": "2017-09-12T12:03:53.716Z",
  "_op": "add",
  "_id": 2
}
```

So far i have done the following using the gson library :-

```
         JsonParser par = new JsonParser();
         JsonElement jsonelement = par.parse(new FileReader("ddJob.json"));
         JsonArray jsonArr = jsonelement.getAsJsonArray();
             for(Object o : jsonArr)
             {
                 JsonObject obj = (JsonObject)(o);
                 JsonObject mArry = obj.getAsJsonObject();
                 String keyVal = mArry.get("key").toString();

                 if(keyVal.equalsIgnoreCase("\"jsonstore.LinkTree\""))
                 {
                    if(mArry.isJsonArray())
                 {
                     System.out.println("It is a JSONArray");
                 }
                 else if(mArry.isJsonObject())
                 {
                     System.out.println("It is a JSONObject");                       
                 }
                 else if(mArry.isJsonPrimitive())
                 {
                     System.out.println("It is a JSONPrimitive");
                 }
                 else if(mArry.isJsonNull())
                 {
                     System.out.println("It is a JSONNull");
                 }
                 }
                // Here it prints ,it is a JSONObject
```

---

I need help from here, I am not able to parse this JSONObject, I cannot get a JSonArray out of it and I am not able to get anything like a primitive etc. I can see in the debugger it has all the information I need. It is unreadable because of the spaces in between.

Can you please let me know how I can parse the rest of this JSON.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The root element is not an array. Have you tried using `getAsJsonObject` (or whatever it is called) instead?

Comment: Sir, Thank you for your help. I notice that you have removed the last "_indexed" portion. That is fine.
When I make the first call and treat it as a JsonObject and use the above call that you have mentioned. I get this error :-

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: [{"key":"__WL_WEBLOG_CONFIG__","value":"{\u0000\"\u0000e\u0000n\ ...............

Comment: Accidentally sorted the properties during pretty-printing. That was unintentional. Fixed.

Comment: Why don't you use Jackson? I think parse this json is pretty easy with it.

Comment: @KudmiSubba : The JSON in the error message is different from the JSON in your question.

Comment: @Henrik : Sir, You are right, I cannot paste that here, it has sensitive information, I have exported that JSON into a text file so that we can read it. Here is the full information :-
1 - This is a WorkLight JsonStore , that is inside the local storage
2 - This I have exported into a text file using DB SQLite

This is what I have to parse.

oleg.cherednik - I will try Jackson, I havent used it before. Thank you.

Comment: @Henrik: Sir, when I parse just the text file that has the above JSON, the jsonElement shows up with only this :- " ÿþ " . Can you please advise me, am I doing something totally wrong?

Comment: ÿþ is 0xfffe in UTF-8; this is the byte order mark in UTF-16. You need to convert your string to UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Java API for JSON Processing](https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/). Jar can be found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.json/1.1).
**This updated version should help with multiple `JSON` objects separated by commas. This version attempts to find the correct comma then splits the string based on those commas.**

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.stream.JsonParser;
import javax.json.stream.JsonParser.Event;
import static javax.json.stream.JsonParser.Event.KEY_NAME;
import static javax.json.stream.JsonParser.Event.VALUE_FALSE;
import static javax.json.stream.JsonParser.Event.VALUE_NUMBER;
import static javax.json.stream.JsonParser.Event.VALUE_STRING;
import static javax.json.stream.JsonParser.Event.VALUE_TRUE;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JSONParserTest {


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String jsonString = "{\n" +
                            "  \"json\": {\n" +
                            "    \"abc\": 0,\n" +
                            "    \"def\": \"100\",\n" +
                            "    \"ghi\": 1,\n" +
                            "    \"jkl\": \"0000000000\",\n" +
                            "    \"mno\": \"3\",\n" +
                            "    \"pqr\": \"COLS, COMPLETE\",\n" +
                            "    \"stu\": 2,\n" +
                            "    \"vwx\": \"0000010000\",\n" +
                            "    \"yz\": \"00\",\n" +
                            "    \"a123\": 31,\n" +
                            "    \"b123\": 1,\n" +
                            "    \"c123\": \"1270\",\n" +
                            "    \"d123\": \"2\",\n" +
                            "    \"e123\": \"00\",\n" +
                            "    \"f123\": 1,\n" +
                            "    \"g123\": \"0000001000\"\n" +
                            "  },\n" +
                            "  \"_indexes\": {\n" +
                            "    \"c123\": [\n" +
                            "      \"1270\"\n" +
                            "    ],\n" +
                            "    \"h123\": [\n" +
                            "      \"1270\"\n" +
                            "    ]\n" +
                            "  },\n" +
                            "  \"_d\": false,\n" +
                            "  \"_dd\": \"2017-09-12T12:03:53.716Z\",\n" +
                            "  \"_op\": \"add\",\n" +
                            "  \"_id\": 2\n" +
                            "},\n" +
                            "{\n" +
                            "  \"json\": {\n" +
                            "    \"abc\": 0,\n" +
                            "    \"def\": \"100\",\n" +
                            "    \"ghi\": 1,\n" +
                            "    \"jkl\": \"0000000000\",\n" +
                            "    \"mno\": \"3\",\n" +
                            "    \"pqr\": \"COLS, COMPLETE\",\n" +
                            "    \"stu\": 2,\n" +
                            "    \"vwx\": \"0000010000\",\n" +
                            "    \"yz\": \"00\",\n" +
                            "    \"a123\": 31,\n" +
                            "    \"b123\": 1,\n" +
                            "    \"c123\": \"1270\",\n" +
                            "    \"d123\": \"2\",\n" +
                            "    \"e123\": \"00\",\n" +
                            "    \"f123\": 1,\n" +
                            "    \"g123\": \"0000001000\"\n" +
                            "  },\n" +
                            "  \"_indexes\": {\n" +
                            "    \"c123\": [\n" +
                            "      \"1270\"\n" +
                            "    ],\n" +
                            "    \"h123\": [\n" +
                            "      \"1270\"\n" +
                            "    ]\n" +
                            "  },\n" +
                            "  \"_d\": false,\n" +
                            "  \"_dd\": \"2017-09-12T12:03:53.716Z\",\n" +
                            "  \"_op\": \"add\",\n" +
                            "  \"_id\": 2\n" +
                            "},\n" +
                            "{\n" +
                            "  \"json\": {\n" +
                            "    \"abc\": 0,\n" +
                            "    \"def\": \"100\",\n" +
                            "    \"ghi\": 1,\n" +
                            "    \"jkl\": \"0000000000\",\n" +
                            "    \"mno\": \"3\",\n" +
                            "    \"pqr\": \"COLS, COMPLETE\",\n" +
                            "    \"stu\": 2,\n" +
                            "    \"vwx\": \"0000010000\",\n" +
                            "    \"yz\": \"00\",\n" +
                            "    \"a123\": 31,\n" +
                            "    \"b123\": 1,\n" +
                            "    \"c123\": \"1270\",\n" +
                            "    \"d123\": \"2\",\n" +
                            "    \"e123\": \"00\",\n" +
                            "    \"f123\": 1,\n" +
                            "    \"g123\": \"0000001000\"\n" +
                            "  },\n" +
                            "  \"_indexes\": {\n" +
                            "    \"c123\": [\n" +
                            "      \"1270\"\n" +
                            "    ],\n" +
                            "    \"h123\": [\n" +
                            "      \"1270\"\n" +
                            "    ]\n" +
                            "  },\n" +
                            "  \"_d\": false,\n" +
                            "  \"_dd\": \"2017-09-12T12:03:53.716Z\",\n" +
                            "  \"_op\": \"add\",\n" +
                            "  \"_id\": 2\n" +
                            "}"; //I am guessing this is how your data looks.


        List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\},\n\\{");//Find this pattern ***MAKE SURE THIS PATTERN IS CORRECT FOR YOU*** Your patter may be "\\},\\{"
        Matcher m = p.matcher(jsonString);
        while(m.find())
        {
            positions.add(m.start() + 1);//save starting position of the found pattern
        }

        System.out.println("# of positions: " + positions.size());
        List<String> jsonStringObjects = new ArrayList();

        if(positions.size() >= 1)
        {
            jsonStringObjects.add(jsonString.substring(0, positions.get(0)));//get first jsonString
            //System.out.println(jsonString.substring(0, positions.get(0)));   
            jsonStringObjects.add(jsonString.substring(positions.get(positions.size() - 1) + 1));//get last jsonString
            //System.out.println(jsonString.substring(positions.get(positions.size() - 1) + 1));   
        }
        if(positions.size() >= 2  )
        for(int i = 0; i < positions.size() - 1; i++)//get all jsonStrings between first and last
        {              
            jsonStringObjects.add(jsonString.substring(positions.get(i) + 1, positions.get(i + 1)));
            //System.out.println(jsonString.substring(positions.get(i) + 1, positions.get(i + 1)));           
        }                

        System.out.println("# of jsonStringObjects: " + jsonStringObjects.size());
        int counter = 0;
        for(String item : jsonStringObjects)
        {
            System.out.println("JSON Object #: " + ++counter);
            try (JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(new StringReader(item))) {
                while (parser.hasNext()) {
                    final Event event = parser.next();
                    switch (event) {
                        case KEY_NAME:
                            String key = parser.getString();
                            System.out.println("\t" + key);
                            break;
                        case VALUE_STRING:
                            String value = parser.getString();
                            System.out.println("\t" + value);
                            break;
                        case VALUE_NUMBER:
                            BigDecimal number = parser.getBigDecimal();
                            System.out.println("\t" + number);
                            break;
                        case VALUE_TRUE:
                            System.out.println("\t" + true);
                            break;
                        case VALUE_FALSE:
                            System.out.println("\t" + false);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

> Output:

```
run:
# of positions: 2
# of jsonStringObjects: 3
JSON Object #: 1
    json
    abc
    0
    def
    100
    ghi
    1
    jkl
    0000000000
    mno
    3
    pqr
    COLS, COMPLETE
    stu
    2
    vwx
    0000010000
    yz
    00
    a123
    31
    b123
    1
    c123
    1270
    d123
    2
    e123
    00
    f123
    1
    g123
    0000001000
    _indexes
    c123
    1270
    h123
    1270
    _d
    false
    _dd
    2017-09-12T12:03:53.716Z
    _op
    add
    _id
    2
JSON Object #: 2
    json
    abc
    0
    def
    100
    ghi
    1
    jkl
    0000000000
    mno
    3
    pqr
    COLS, COMPLETE
    stu
    2
    vwx
    0000010000
    yz
    00
    a123
    31
    b123
    1
    c123
    1270
    d123
    2
    e123
    00
    f123
    1
    g123
    0000001000
    _indexes
    c123
    1270
    h123
    1270
    _d
    false
    _dd
    2017-09-12T12:03:53.716Z
    _op
    add
    _id
    2
JSON Object #: 3
    json
    abc
    0
    def
    100
    ghi
    1
    jkl
    0000000000
    mno
    3
    pqr
    COLS, COMPLETE
    stu
    2
    vwx
    0000010000
    yz
    00
    a123
    31
    b123
    1
    c123
    1270
    d123
    2
    e123
    00
    f123
    1
    g123
    0000001000
    _indexes
    c123
    1270
    h123
    1270
    _d
    false
    _dd
    2017-09-12T12:03:53.716Z
    _op
    add
    _id
    2
```

Comment: Sir , I am trying your suggestion, I will update you in a few minutes. 
cricket_007 -- I thank you for that, I didnt realize it may be UTF-16. Thanks.

Comment: @Sedrick Jefferson - Sir, This is working well, but can you please let me know how I could read an entire JSON file using this JsonParser.

The issue is, when the entire record is read ( as above ) that is one record, and then there is a comma , that starts a new record like , {"json":... , at this point, the code throws an exception "Invalid token=COMMA ............ " . I checked the line number and column no that it suggested, it is indeed the comma separator. I will research this issue, but if you know this can you please suggest how I work around this. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am guessing that the comma causes the JSON to be invalid. What I would do is read the whole file to `String`. Next, I would split the `String` on the comma. Finally, I would handle each split `ArrayList`/ `Array` of `String`s individually.

Comment: Suggested won't work. There are a lot of commas in the `JSON` and you only want to split on a specific one.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to split on ",{" and see if that works. It really helped me. Thanks.

Comment: If you split of that you will lose `{`.

Comment: Did you get it to completely work correctly? If not, I can update the answer with a solution that I think will completely solve your problem.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson - Sir, I havent finished it yet, but I am processing the string one by one. Instead of writing this EXPORTED data into one file, I am creating N files. This is not a smart way, but my challenge now is to export all the data so that it can be operated upon. If you do find a way please help  me.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson - Sir, Thank you very much. I am trying it now, I will update you by tomorrow morning.